# How can I make a button appear after scrolling X amount in Angular5?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular5

I am making an Angular5 application. After scrolling past a carousel on my homepage, I want a button to appear in the screen which can bring you back to the top.

I tried doing this using   **@HostListener("window:scroll", [])**. I figured out how the button brings you back to the top but I don't know how to make it appear after specifically scrolling past the carousel.

This is what I currently have, the ??? is the part that I don't know.

```
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onScroll(): string {
    if (window.pageYOffset <= ???) {
      return this.state;
    }
  }
```

State is a string: 'none', to set the style.sisplay dynamically via HTML property binding.

Here is a sketch of my application to make things clearer.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your scroll event check the value of y to see if it is greater than the carousel position, if so, return a visible display type,

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onScroll(): string {
    let carouselElement = document.getElementById('yourElementId');
    let carouselRect = carouselElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    let carouselYPos = carouselRect.top;

    if (window.pageYOffset <=carouselYPos) {
      return this.state;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but my question was what I had to place on the ??? spot. How can I tell Angular to display it when the top of the page goes below the carousel?

Comment: @Mike no problem, sorry for the lame answer on my part, I would just use javascript's element.getBoundingClientRect().top to get the y value of the carousel and use that to replace the ???, I updated my answer

Comment: @Mike I believe my updated answer should give you what you need.

Comment: @Mike, awesome. Glad I could help.